# Is there simpler way to do DTO validations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

Currently I am working in spring boot projects to create a micro services. I like the idea of using `javax.validation.constrainsts.*` annotations to do simple validation stuff like checking for `NotNull` and `Size` validations and then catching all those validation constraints in one go using `javax.validation.Validator`. But if I want to add some custom validations for some fields, like for example if I have an age field, and I would check if that age is valid if it's greater than 18, is there any easier and cleaner way of doing such validations, considering that I have many fields in my class.

Looking at the existing codebase, I see that other people have written a function for each of the fields, that would validate the particular field. Then call all such functions from one place to get all the errors. It seemed like there should definitely be a more convenient way than this approach.

I also know that I can create my own javax constraint validation by creating my own annotations which I learnt from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-compound). Is there easier way of doing this apart from writing my own annotation along with another class that implements `ConstraintValidator`. I am using Java 11 by the way, functional programming method would also be good.

I got the idea of following the same procedure as for creating custom constraint validation. But in the annotation I would add another field like this,

```
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = Validator.class)
public @interface Validate {
 // Extra field 
 Function<Object, Boolean> func();

 String message() default "Invalid";

 Class<?>[] groups() default {};

 Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

So now I should be able to pass in a custom function to the annotation, can use the same annotation for all the fields, but use different functions as required, like:

```
@Validate(func = field1Validator)
private String field1;

@Validate(func = field2Validator)
private String field2;
```

The advantage of doing this is that I would still be able to catch all the constraint violations in one one. But the problem here is that java doesn't allow for Function in annotations.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you are re-inventing [hibernate validator library](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator-java-bean-validation/)

Comment: Not necessarily reinventing anything, it's just the other way that it is done in the existing codebase is creating a separate isValid function for each field, then calling each of those isValid functions is another function.

Comment: This would suggest `Validator` would eventually grow into a monstrous god class and probably not re-usable for other objects which need _similar_ validation.